# Meaning of the construction noun + "but" + phrasal verb

Tags: expressions

I came across some usages of the construction noun + "but" + "can" of which I can only recall one:

> No truth but can be pried away from this book.

Actually the full example is from a poem, "No truth but can be pried away//by Archimedes' lever - // for which no fulcrum can be found.// Not anywhere. Not ever.", but I don't think this context adds anything to it.

My intuition fails me, I can't tell if the meaning here is "the book contains no truths" or perhaps "one can barely/merely get some truth out of the book" or maybe something else?

From the full example I can deduce that the meaning is more likely to be the first one, but then what is the role the "but" plays anyway? Is it just there for literariness? If not, some other similar examples for this construction would also be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'prying away a truth' is supposed to mean, but the sense is 'There is no truth that cannot be pried away' (no truths exist except those that can be).

Comment: It's not a "phrasal verb". It's a **verb phrase**. They're not the same. As for the structure, this is a [Nobbut-cleft](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other interpretations might be possible, but I'll give one.

The sentence is missing the pronoun "what":

> No truth but what can be pried away by Archimedes' lever--for which no fulcrum can be found.

"But" is [a preposition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but) here (meaning "except"), and its object is the nominal clause "what can be pried away by Archimedes' lever". (This is therefore not really a sentence but simply a noun phrase.) It means that the only truths are those that can be be pried away by Archimedes' lever, and the author then points out that such a lever doesn't exist. (Archimedes supposedly said that with the right lever, he could move the Earth.)